# I get a 400 status code error from a GitHub Pages deployment

Tags: github, github-pages, github-pages-deploy-action

During an automated "pages build and deployment" workflow, I get the following error:

> Error: Request failed with status code 400

This is just a static site, no jekyll or anything like that (I have a `.nojekyll` file in the root) and it's worked fine for several years until today.

I've opened a ticket on GitHub support, but in case anyone here can help me in the meantime... Is there anything I can do to try to resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

It could be the side-effect of (from two days ago)

> ### [GitHub Pages: using GitHub Actions for builds and deployments for public repositories](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-12-16-github-pages-using-github-actions-for-builds-and-deployments-for-public-repositories/)

> Today you will begin to see a new workflow running called pages build and deployment in your public GitHub Pages repositories.
>
> This workflow is automatically triggered when you push to the branch configured for GitHub Pages in your repository.
> As the name suggests, it builds and deploys your pages site.
>
> The initial benefit of this change is enabling you to see your build logs and any errors that may occur which has been a long standing issue for Pages users.
> However, in the future this will enable us to give you the ability to fully customize your pages build and deployment workflow to use any static site generator you want without having to push the build output to a special branch of the repository.
>
> You may notice this workflow uses some new actions `actions/pages-deploy`, and `actions/jekyll-build-pages`.
> For now these actions are designed to be used in the generated workflow, however, starting early next year we will introduce some additional changes that will enable you to take advantage of them.
>
> Learn more about GitHub Pages

So [`Cecilapp/GitHub-Pages-deploy`](https://github.com/Cecilapp/GitHub-Pages-deploy) (the [GitHub Pages deploy](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/gh-pages-deploy)) workflow you might be using) might behave differently in light of those recent changes.